React Native Flatlist Auto Scrolling
i have an flatlist component which i would like to make it auto scrolling.
<FlatList
        contentContainerStyle={{}}
        data={banners}
        renderItem={(item) => (
          <Image source={{ uri: item.item }} style={styles.image} />
        )}
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        snapToInterval={width}
        snapToAlignment={'center'}
        decelerationRate={'fast'}
      />

Here is the component so far what property i need for it instead of setInterval any other idea?
I have searched some old solutions from past year which are outdated already. I would like to have something with less lines of code and easier to apply.

If you want minimal lines of code and don't want to handle triggering the scroll yourself, you should use a carousel package like this one:
https://github.com/dohooo/react-native-reanimated-carousel#readme
